# Горизонтальное меню

Tags: css3, меню, html, html5, css

Здравствуйте. У меня возникла проблема. Необходимо сделать горизонтальное меню, которое при масштабировании страницы или при смене величины шрифта, не съезжало бы и не ломалось. Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение, подтолкните в поиске) буду вам очень признателен, так как перепробовал уже много вариантов.

P.S. Код наработок приводить не стал, так как у меня было много вариантов, и я думаю, что проще подсказать решение, чем исправлять мое творчество.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте значения `width` и `min-width` в CSS для блока вашего горизонтального меню.